# Prolog falling into infinite loop

Tags: loops, recursion, prolog, infinite, transitivity

I'm trying to define the rule of "My friend's friend is my friend" in prolog, and I have the following code:

```
friends(john,jake).
friends(mike,hans).
friends(hans,robert).
friends(robert,angela).

mutual_friendship(X,Y):-
    friends(X,Y); 
    friends(Y,X).

friendship(X,Y):- 
    mutual_friendship(X,Y),!;
    mutual_friendship(Y,Z), friendship(Z,X).
```

And it does that pretty well, it is capable to detect friendship between Mike and Angela through Hans and Robert, the problem is when I try to find friendship between John and Angela, for example, who are not linked, but the program falls into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

`mutual_friendship/2` is not slightly related here, I suppose.

```
friendship(X,Y):-
    ( friends(X,Y)
    ; friends(X,Z), friendship(Z,Y)
    ).
```

And for given facts

```
friends(john,jake).
friends(mike,hans).
friends(hans,robert).
friends(robert,angela).
```

we could get

```
?- friendship(john,angela).
false.

?- friendship(mike,angela).
true .
```

Comment: I get what you're saying, but given the friends that have been defined, surely that rule would match nobody? Something isn't right there.

Comment: But can you do now friendship(mike,angela). ?

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ's solution (+1) is asymmetric but finite (this is why `friendship(mike,angela)` works but `friendship(angela,mike)` does not). The original is symmetric but infinite. If we want symmetry and finiteness we're going to have to either handle asymmetry at the top (more elegant IMO) or keep track of what edges we've traversed in an undirected graph.

Comment: What do you mean with "handle asymmetry at the top"?